# Windows into new mathematical worlds

Tags: ho.history-overview, gm.general-mathematics

Yitang Zhang's *Annals of Mathematics* primes-gap result
opened a new window, which 
[Polymath's reduction](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes) from $70\times 10^6$ to $246$ attests.
Perhaps
Harald Helfgott's
celebrated proof of the [odd Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture)
has not similarly open new avenues—or at least not yet.
Certainly the [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) has opened new windows.
Perhaps the
[Guth-Katz breakthrough on the Erdős distance problem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/the-guth-katz-bound-on-the-erdos-distance-problem/)
has opened new windows.

My question is,

> ***Q***. Which results in the recent past (~last decade+) have opened 
>   significant windows into new mathematics?

I realize this is quite subjective,
but it requires a high-level view of fields of mathematics
to notice this while it is happening, in a way that others (like me) without that
expertise cannot discern.
It would be educational to learn of expert opinions, without diminishing
the significance of any particular result.
Rather I am hoping for a celebration of those results which seem not to be
the end of a line of investigation, but rather a new beginning.

Comment: If Zhang himself had proved the 246 bound, would it still have opened new avenues?

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question seems too broad and vague.  I don't even understand the stated example of Zhang versus Helfgott.  Does it just have to do with whether the paper triggers a minor industry of followup papers?  This happens all the time.

Comment: (I have asked the moderators to close the question.)

Comment: With some slight reluctance, I'll grant Joseph's request. The idea behind the question seems to me to have merit, so perhaps tweaking is all that's needed?

Comment: It seems similar in spirit to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83290/noteworthy-achievements-in-and-around-2010  The trouble I see is that every significant piece of new mathematics lets us see something new and hence could be construed as a "new window". Possible sharper questions might be, what are some new techniques that suddenly allowed a wide range of old problems to be solved?  Or, what are some new subfields of mathematics (perhaps measured by the Mathematics Subject Classification) that were created by a single seminal paper?

Answer (score 7):

The work of Lurie, and others (for instance, Rezk, Joyal, and also older work of Toen, Vezzosi, Simpson, ...) on [Higher Topos Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_Topos_Theory) and [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/higheralgebra.pdf), leading to e.g. a proof of the [cobordism hypothesis](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cobordism+hypothesis) (see also [Freed's article](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-01/S0273-0979-2012-01393-9/)) and the proof of the [Weil conjecture on Tamagawa numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjecture_on_Tamagawa_numbers) for function fields over finite fields.

I'm making this community wiki so others can add things.

Comment: I've added a link to Lurie's Higher Algebra. I think derived algebraic geometry should also be mentioned.

Comment: I agree, but I was trying to think what it has been used for: clearly thinking about eg equivariant elliptic cohomology