# Breakthroughs in mathematics in 2021

Tags: big-list, big-picture

This is somehow a general (and naive) question, but as specialized mathematicians we usually miss important results outside our area of research.

So, generally speaking, which have been important breakthroughs in 2021 in different mathematical disciplines?

Comment: Mathematics tend to be slow. It's rare to see a breakthrough "in that year" go from preprint announcement, to review, to accepted, to actually published. It's not impossible, but those tend to be shorter, smaller, e.g. some counterexample of some finite conjecture. Otherwise, things tend to take time. That's a good thing.

Comment: Also, 2021 is not over.  I still have a week to do something big!

Comment: @Kimball: We're working on it!!!

Comment: What do you mean by _important breakthroughs_? For understanding my question see these levels in math research: ordinary paper < good quality paper < systematic papers answering some important conjectures < works that lead to a new sub-branch of math (like Ricci flow inside of differential geometry/topology) < works that discover/introduce a new branch of math (such k-theory and category theory) and so on. There is also a [breakthrough prize in math](https://breakthroughprize.org/Prize/3). Which one is related to your post?

Comment: A similar question was asked about ten years ago: [Noteworthy achievements in and around 2010?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/83290)

Comment: For a good story on The Year in Math and Computer Science, see also [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-year-in-math-and-computer-science-20211223/)

Comment: From the answers, it seems that a good way to notice important results outside of our specialty is to read Quanta magazine

Comment: It's definitely possible to learn something from the answers to this kind of question, but it's worth bearing in mind that answers are pretty much limited to various papers in one or  two prestige journals, and/or those papers which Quanta writers chose to pay attention to. So it's hard to get a balanced perspective.

Answer (score 52):

[Advancing mathematics by guiding human intuition with AI](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-04086-x), Nature **600**, 70 (2021), stands out because it represents the first significant advance in pure mathematics generated by artificial intelligence.

More newsworthy items (each item has a link to a blog on Quanta magazine for an informal discussion of its significance):

- [A counterexample to the
  unit conjecture for group rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11818), Giles Gardam, Ann. of Math. **194**, 967 (2021). [[Quanta link](https://arxiv.org/tb/redirect/1838121/be7b37591)]
- <s>[Tadayuki Watanabe](https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-tadayuki-watanabe-solved-a-topological-mystery-about-spheres-20211026/) solved the last open case of the Smale conjecture.</s> <sub>(still unpublished in 2021)</sub>
- [$MM^{++}$ implies $(\ast)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10213), David Asperó and Ralf Schindler, Ann. Math. **193**, 793 (2021). [[Quanta link](https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-many-numbers-exist-infinity-proof-moves-math-closer-to-an-answer-20210715)]
- [Proof of the p-adic formula for Brumer–Stark units](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.02516), Samit Dasgupta and Mahesh Kakde. [[Quanta link](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-find-polynomial-building-blocks-hilbert-sought-20210525/)]
- [Geometrization of the local Langlands correspondence](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.13459), Laurent Fargues and Peter Scholze. [[Quanta link](https://arxiv.org/tb/redirect/1839294/637a3cc77)]
- [Proof of Arnold's conjecture for cyclical number systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01507), Mohammed Abouzaid and Andrew Blumberg. [[Quanta link](https://arxiv.org/tb/redirect/1840598/934810366)]

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to post different answers for different breakthroughs? I think it might be useful to see how much each one is upvoted.

Comment: The first paragraph is very debatable.

Comment: Watanabe's Arxiv preprint is 3 years old. Is there something new, e.g. is the paper accepted somewhere?

Comment: @abx --- it's still unpublished and I have crossed it out from the list.

Comment: The proof that $\sf MM^{++}$ implies $(*)$ is not from 2021. It was published in 2021, yes. But it is definitely older. The [preprint on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10213) is from 2019, and I know that they took a few months to write this properly. David told me about this breakthrough as it was happening, but I don't remember if it was late 2018 or early 2019 right now.

Comment: I presume this applies to all substantial math research, that there is not a single moment in time when it happens; I would argue that the date of publication in a refereed journal is the date it enters into the mathematical body of knowledge.

Comment: Do you have the Quanta Magazine links as well?

Comment: added the Quanta Magazine links

Comment: Watanabe very recently posted this https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.01609.pdf . In the acknowledgement he also thanked the referee for their comments. Me and one of my collaborator read some part of his paper while writing our very recent paper. I am not in a state to judge if it is correct or not, but I haven't met anyone who doubted his proof yet. It's just a very ground breaking technique. And we (me and Jianfeng Lin) able to prove that gauge theory cannot detect such things.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker oh, like IUT? That got published this year in a refereed journal ;-)

Comment: @SamHopkins Speaking of which, anything in Proof Systems?

Comment: The media hype around the AI work seems highly debatable, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.04324 (a direct response to the Nature article linked to in the answer)

Answer (score 40):

Strictly speaking this is not a new mathematical result (meaning no new proof), but let me mention the [Liquid Tensor Experiment](https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean-liquid/), the verification in Lean of a very recent theorem by Clausen and Scholze.

[Here](https://xenaproject.wordpress.com/2020/12/05/liquid-tensor-experiment/) is the original post by Scholze, [here](https://xenaproject.wordpress.com/2021/06/05/half-a-year-of-the-liquid-tensor-experiment-amazing-developments/) the story six months later, the canonical [quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/lean-computer-program-confirms-peter-scholze-proof-20210728/) link and, last but not least, a [nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01627-2) article.

PS: I participated in the project, so my opinion about its importance is surely biased.

Comment: Not to be confused with the Liquid Tension Experiment, who released a new album this year.

Comment: With a song titled "Solid Resolution Theory" :D

Comment: @Ricky I interpreted that as a loose word-for-word antonym of the band name, but it is eerily relevant...

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn Sure, the name of the project was related to the name of the band, but "Solid Resolution Theory" arrived later!

Answer (score 32):

One of the most exciting developments in combinatorics in 2021 is the proof of the Erdos-Faber-Lovasz Conjecture on the chromatic index of hypergraphs. There is a [good article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-settle-erdos-coloring-conjecture-20210405) in Quanta magazine about the proof.

Comment: ... for large enough vertex numbers. I don't get why everyone is so cavalier about this.

Answer (score 28):

In (analytic) number theory Paul Nelson's recent preprint (https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.15230) solved the subconvexity problem for a huge class of L-functions in the t-aspect.

More precisely subconvexity bounds for $L(\frac{1}{2}+it, \pi, St)$ are established for cuspidal automorphic representations of $GL_n$.

This is a huge breakthrough and also the methods are very exciting and promising.

**Edit:** Now there is an article on this result on [Quanta magazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-clear-hurdle-in-quest-to-decode-prime-numbers-20220113/).

Answer (score 25):

My favourite theorems in mathematics are the ones that at the same time great and have easy-to-understand formulation. To put aside various P=NP claims in arxiv, I will concentrate on theorems that where peer-reviewed and published in 2021. Most of them appeared in arxiv before.

So, the greatest easy-to-understand theorems published in 2021 are:

- Theorem of Annika Heckel about non-concentration of the chromatic number of a random graph https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2021-34-01/S0894-0347-2020-00957-2/
- A dramatic progress on sunflower conjecture by Alweiss, Lovett, Wu and Zhang https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/194-3/p05
- The resolution of the rectangular peg problem for smooth Jordan curves by Greene and Lobb
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/194-2/p04
- Characterization of fields of values of odd-degree irreducible characters by Navarro and Tiep
  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-pi/article/fields-of-values-of-characters-of-degree-not-divisible-by-p/0FE327DAE6088EC9B43A0CFAFC8E8D52
- Proof that the Dehn function of $\mathrm{SL}_4({\mathbb Z})$ is quadratic by Leuzinger and Young
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/193-3/p02
- Proof that the group $\mathrm{Aut}(F_n)$ has Kazhdan's property (T) for all $n \geq 6$ by Kaluba, Kielak and Nowak
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/193-2/p03
- Characterization of $\frac{3}{2}$-generated groups by Burness, Guralnick and Harper https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/193-2/p05
- A counterexample to the unit conjecture for group rings by Gardam
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/194-3/p09
- Proof of the universal optimality of the ${E}_8$ and Leech lattices by Cohn, Kumar, Miller, Radchenko and Viazovska
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/articles/17703
- New bounds on the density of lattice coverings by  Ordentlich, Regev and Weiss
  https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2022-35-01/S0894-0347-2021-00984-0/home.html
- Determining, for each given fixed angle and in all sufficiently large dimensions, the maximum number of lines pairwise separated by the given angle by Jiang, Tidor, Yao, Zhang and Zhao
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/194-3/p03
- The isoperimetric inequality for minimal surfaces by Brendle
  https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2021-34-02/S0894-0347-2021-00969-4/
- A connection between thresholds and fractional expectation-thresholds established by Frankston, Kahn, Narayanan and Park
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/194-2/p02
- An almost constant lower bound of the isoperimetric coefficient in the KLS conjecture by Chen
  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-021-00558-4
- An $O(n \log n)$ algorithm for multiplication of $n$-digit integers by Harvey and van der Hoeven
  https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/193-2/p04
- An explicit construction of polynomials with optimal condition number by Beltran, Etayo, Marzo and Ortega-Cerd
  https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2021-34-01/S0894-0347-2020-00956-0/

I am sorry if you think that this list is too long but in my opinion all these theorems are both great and beautiful, so I will let you to choose your own 3-5 favourite ones.

Finally, you may want to look at my book
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-80627-9
with the descriptions of all such theorems published from 2001 until now.

Comment: I got your book from the library and have been reading it voraciously. It is excellent!

Comment: Thank you! I am very happy that you like it!

Answer (score 22):

Having just listened to some of Jacob Tsimerman's [Minerva lectures](https://www.math.princeton.edu/events/seminars/minerva-mini-course/archive/240), I became aware of the recent arXiv preprint, [Canonical Heights on Shimura Varieties and the André–Oort Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.08788), by Jonathan Pila, Ananth N. Shankar, Jacob Tsimerman, Hélène Esnault, and Michael Groechenig.  Assuming the paper is correct, it gives the first unconditional (i.e., not assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis) proof of the full [André–Oort Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9%E2%80%93Oort_conjecture).  The proof builds on a lot of previous work and knits together a wide variety of techniques and ideas, but one thing that I find personally appealing is that the theory of [o-minimality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory) plays a key role behind the scenes.  A priori, one might not guess that model theory has much to say about counting rational points, but it does!

Comment: Of course an important link between model theory and counting rational points is the Pila-Wilkie theorem!

Comment: And here is the link to the expected [Quanta article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-prove-30-year-old-andre-oort-conjecture-20220203/).

Answer (score 20):

Dmitri Pavlov and Daniel Grady released a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01095) containing the first complete proof of the Cobordism Hypothesis, and in fact they prove a significant generalization to cobordism categories with geometric structure. Their article has a good discussion of prior work on this problem.

Answer (score 11):

Since other answers mention works *published* in 2021, I think one can add to the list the proof of triviality of the $\phi^4$ quantum field theory in four dimensions:

Michael Aizenman, Hugo Duminil-Copin,
["Marginal triviality of the scaling limits of critical 4D Ising and $\lambda\phi_4^4$ models"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematics/volume-194/issue-1/Marginal-triviality-of-the-scaling-limits-of-critical-4D-Ising/10.4007/annals.2021.194.1.3.short), Ann. of Math. (2) 194(1): 163-235 (July 2021).

Answer (score 1):

The negative answer by counterexample to the *Modular Isomorphism Problem*
for group rings (that is, the question whether for $p$-groups $G$ and $H$,
the group rings ${\mathbb F}_p G$ and ${\mathbb F}_p H$ are isomorphic
only if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic) by Garcia-Lucas, Margolis and del Rio.

*García-Lucas, Diego; Margolis, Leo; del Río, Ángel*, [**Non-isomorphic 2-groups with isomorphic modular group algebras**](https://doi.org/10.1515/crelle-2021-0074), J. Reine Angew. Math. 783, 269-274 (2022). [ZBL1514.20019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1514.20019).